# ADFS 2016 - OAuth2 SPA - Get a new token silently

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application, adfs4.0

I have a SPA where the user authenticates in ADFS and the application gets an access token. I am trying to use JS code to simulate the functionality of ADAL JS where a hidden iframe is used to make a request to ADFS to get the new token.

This is the 'src' value of the iframe:

> https://../adfs/oauth2/authorize?client_id=...&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=...&prompt=none&domain_hint=...&login_hint=...&nonce=...

The ADFS is configured with two realms: AD and ADLDS (LDAP). Because of this I am not sure what values I need to pass on domain_hint & login_hint parameters for a user in ADLDS.

The request fails with message:

> https://....html?client-request-id=...#error=login_required&error_description=MSIS9621%3a+Unable+to+handle+the+OAuth+authorization+request+without+getting+user+input.

The ADFS event viewer shows this error:

> Exception details: 
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.Exceptions.OAuthNoPassiveException: MSIS9233: There are multiple identity providers found for OAuth Authorization request with prompt set to none. Unable to complete home realm discovery.

Is this functionality actually supported in ADFS 2016? Any idea as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: George, have you tried the things from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The `prompt=none` request parameter says that you want to pass the process the `/authorize` request without user interaction. But during its processing, there is something that needs user interaction - the server probably doesn't know which identity provider to choose, so it returns the error. If you make the same request just by pasting the `/authorize` URL to your browser without the `prompt=none` parameter, the server will probably give you a possibility to choose a provider.

You wrote you would like to get an access token, but your `/authorize` URL contains `response_type=id_token`. If you want an access token, the parameter should be `response_type=token` (see [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1)).

Looking at the [Azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-authentication-for-federated-users-portal), the `domain_hint` request param is supported of OpenID Connect, so your request `scope` parameter [should contain](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) `openid` value. It's also necessary for getting an ID token (if you want it).